# Giving 'TemplateError' can't convert String into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I recently transfered my app from Rails2 to Rails3.

The code in 'app/views/distribution/index.html.erb' is like :-

```
<div style="padding-bottom:10px; padding-left:0px;float:left;display:<%= (!session[:album][@artist.id.to_s].empty? && !session[:album][@artist.id.to_s].nil?)?'block' : 'none' %>" id = "make_payment_enabled">

<%= link_to 'Make Payments',{:action => 'pay', :album=>@album.id}, :class => "button" %>

</div>
```

It's giving me TemplateError on line :-

```
<div style="padding-bottom:10px; padding-left:0px;float:left;display:<%= (!session[:album][@artist.id.to_s].empty? && !session[:album][@artist.id.to_s].nil?)?'block' : 'none' %>" id = "make_payment_enabled">
```

How to resolve the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:** In the ERB tag, try putting spaces around the 'or' question mark, i.e. `....nil?) ? 'block...`.

**Solution Better:** Do step one, then put that code in a helper.  Will really help to clean up your views.

---

**UPDATE**:

A few other tips: you will want to switch the order of the conditions, because you will want to see if the value is `nil` before checking if it's an empty string.

Calling `obj.blank?` is the equivalent of calling `obj.nil? && obj.empty?`, so that could make the code a bit shorter.  Even better, `obj.present?` is the same as `!obj.blank?`.

Therefore, that line could be simplified to:

```
session[:album][@artist.id.to_s].present? ? 'block' : 'none'
```

Happy Rails-ing!